# jQuery not updating inline style with .css() in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make a map on a contact page display full view port width. I'm using the 7 theme and my page content is written in HTML with Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery (specifically I use JADE and SASS but I'm sure that's irrelevant). My JavaScript is enqueued properly and console logs verified. This script runs no problem in a "vanilla" environment.

So I do a calculation to set the negative margin of an iFrame google map to the difference of the container and the view port width

Here's my JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  var $map = $("#map");
  var $mapWrap = $(".map-container");
  var margin = 0;

  margin = -.5 * ($(window).width() - $mapWrap.width());
  console.log($mapWrap.width());
  console.log($(window).width());
  console.log(margin);
  $map.css("margin", "0 " + margin);
  $(window).resize(function(){
    margin = -.5 * ($(window).width() - $mapWrap.width());
    $map.css("margin", "0 " + margin);    
  })
});
```

The console:

1140

1904

-382

Outside of WordPress this works like a charm and have used something similar a bunch of times. Upon inspection of the html page, jQuery adds a style inline attribute to the html element normally but in the WordPress environment the only inline style that gets added is `style="border: 0"`.

As a test I even tried to `addClass("randomClass")` but it wouldn't add said class. I'm led to believe it's a permission issue but I have exhausted all of my knowledge on this subject and am at the mercy of you fine folks. If I can figure this out someone will have to go with a non-full-width map on their contact page and that's just frightening.

Comment: I think your JS code doesn't get executed, otherwise `addClass` would work for sure. Please try [using this widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-javascript-in-text-widgets/)

Comment: Your problem is the calculation of a string with a number in this object "$map.css("margin", "0 " + margin);" 
In this case the type of "0" is a string and the type of the calcuation of "var margin" is a number. so JS will concat your string and your number to a string. For Example if the result of "margin" is 100 the result of "0" + 100 would be 1100.

Comment: The question is, do you really need JS for this layout? It seems like you're trying to offset using a negative margin that is half the size difference of two elements. Depending on how your markup is structured, this might be easily implemented using CSS transforms only.

Comment: @Daniel Pfisterer Im actually going for them to be strings and that the resulting json obj would be {"margin", "0 -382"}. Like i said I've used this code outside of the wordpress theme and it works great. The problem is that the .css() call is not effecting #map by adding a style="margin: 0 -382" attribute and this issue is only happening on the wordpress / possibly theme that im using now.

Comment: @terry The reason I'm using the negative margins is because the content is within the themes container and i need it to over lap the normal containers and be full width. Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting if so any points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.